# Mutation Observer: How To Get Current Data From Mutation Record?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have an `<img>` element whose `src` is changed dynamically. When the change occurs, the MutationObserver is fired and a MutationRecord is recorded. The problem is when I try to access the data from the MutationRecord, it's giving me the old data.

For example:

This is the original `img` element.

```
<img src="#" />
```

JS

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
console.log(mutations);
console.log(mutations[0].target.currentSrc);


});

var element = document.querySelector("#shirt-design");

observer.observe(element, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true
});
```

After the `src` is changed dynamically, `currentSrc` should be something like "image.jpg". The MutationRecord shows the new data, but when I try to access it directly, it shows me the old data.

For example

```
console.log(mutations[0].target.currentSrc);  //shows #

console.log(mutations[0].target.currentSrc);  //SHOULD BE image.jpg
```

**How can I access the current data from the MutationRecord?**

EDIT

What I want from the MutationRecord is `naturalWidth`. It gives me `0` as if the `src` were `#`(which it was). **How do I get `naturalWidth` of the current image?**

```
console.log(mutations[0].target.naturalWidth);  //0
console.log(mutations[0].target.naturalWidth);  //SHOULD BE number > 0
```

EDIT 2

I even tried this code below(within the MutationObserver function) and the result was `0`, which leads me to believe that the MutationRecord is from *before* the change or the `observer` is firing before the change is made.

```
console.log(document.querySelector("#shirt-design").naturalWidth); //0
```

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: `.target` is the Node the mutation affected. And why the `childList: true` for an `<img />`?

Comment: Are you sure it's just `src`? Maybe it's the entire node that's replaced?

Comment: @wOxxOm the only thing that is being changed is the `src` using jQuery `attr()`

Comment: Well, try reading `src` property, not currentSrc (it's only for media elements with `source` sub-elements so maybe it's updated after the mutation callback is invoked).

Comment: @wOxxOm in the MutationRecord, `currentSrc` is the property within the `target` object

Comment: Just because it's a property doesn't mean its update can't be delayed.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh you mean try reading the `src` from the element directly? Like this: `document.querySelector("img").getAttribute("src")` ?

Comment: No, I meant `.src` but this is also worth trying (no need for querySelector though, just use `mutations[0].target.getAttribute`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126701/discussion-between-josan-iracheta-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out that MutationRecord was being retrieved before the `<img>` finished loading. All I had to do was wait for it to load and I was able to get the correct data from the MutationRecord.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  console.log(mutations);
  //wait for img to load
  document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("load", function(){
    console.log(mutations[0].target.currentSrc);
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you want to do and it may be a bit late to ask but why do you add the eventlistener inside the observer? If you just need the img dimensions you only need the listener. This could also come in handy: [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)